# React Native - Upload multiple images in one request?

Tags: react-native

So I have this code for uploading images. If I upload a single image it works, but if I upload a list of images then `request.FILES` will be empty.

```
  const createFormData = (photos, body = {}) => {
    const data = new FormData();

    if (photos.length > 1) {
      const image_list = [];
      for (var i = 1; i < photos.length; i++) {
        const photo = photos[i];
        image_list.push({
          name: photo.fileName,
          type: photo.type,
          uri: Platform.OS === "ios" ? photo.uri.replace("file://", "") : photo.uri,
        });
      }
      console.log(image_list)
      data.append("images", image_list);
    }

    Object.keys(body).forEach((key) => {
      data.append(key, body[key]);
    });

    return data;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The Problem

you are trying to append a **list** of images instead of appending them one by one in `data.append("images", image_list);`

##### The Solution:

use `append` method instead of pushing images into the `image_list` array:

```
const data = new FormData();

if (photos.length > 1) {

  for (var i = 1; i < photos.length; i++) {
    const photo = photos[i];
    data.append('images', {
      name: photo.fileName,
      type: photo.type,
      uri: Platform.OS === "ios" ? photo.uri.replace("file://", "") : photo.uri,
    });
  }
}
```

##### Explanation:

according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), you can append multiple **values** with the same **key**:

```
formData.append('name', true);
formData.append('name', 74);
formData.append('name', 'John');

formData.getAll('name'); // ["true", "74", "John"]
```

##### Optional

You can also use `forEach` function to do the same thing without a `for` loop:

```
const data = formData();

if(photos?.length > 1) {
  photos.forEach( (photo) => {
    data.append('images', {
      name: photo.fileName,
      type: photo.type,uri: Platform.OS === "ios" ? photo.uri.replace("file://", "") : photo.uri,
    })
  })
}
```